# Cloud Function Not Returning Any Documents

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Over the last couple of days my Cloud Functions have been failing for reasons I can't figure out. A basic query to fetch a document is not returning anything.

I've been through the documentation, and since this is such a simple query, I'm not sure where it could be failing. I've hardcoded the document reference number and I'm sure the document exists.

I'm only facing this issue from Cloud Functions. I'm able to query the table and return the document from a Flutter app I'm building.

```
exports.sendEventInvites = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    return sendEventInvites.send(data, context).then((result) => {
        return result;
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        return {
            status: 500,
            message: 'Failed to create event document',
        }
    });
});

function send(event, context) {
  let db = admin.firestore();
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        db.collection(`users`).doc('hardcoded-value').get().then(doc => {
            if (!doc.exists) {
                console.log("Failed to fetch organizer document. Invites not sent");
                return resolve({
                    status: 501,
                    message: "Failed to send invites"
                });
            }
            // a bunch of code here that never gets executed because doc.exists is false
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            return resolve({
                status: 503,
                message: "Failed to send invites"
            });
        });
    });
}
```

I'm not getting any errors, just no document. I've tried initializing admin both ways from the documentation:

```
admin.initializeApp({credential: admin.credential.cert(require('./secret-doc')), databaseURL: "db-url"});
```

and

```
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

I'm using the following relevant npm modules:

```
"@google-cloud/firestore": "^2.2.4"
"firebase-admin": "^8.2.0"
"firebase-functions": "^3.1.0"
"firebase-tools": "^7.1.0"
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I've tried initializing admin both ways from the documentation:

admin.initializeApp({credential: admin.credential.cert(require('./secret-doc')), databaseURL: "db-url"});

and

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

Comment: If you have information to add to your question, you can just edit the question rather than adding a comment.

Comment: Thanks Doug. It was 4 am and I couldn't find the Edit button. lol

Comment: how was this resolved ?